# How can I see ALL global shortcuts currently active across Finder + other apps?

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I've just started using Amethyst and would love to be able to use the `CTRL+optn+NumPad[0-9]` shortcuts, but some of these just don't work and I'm assuming something else already has these shortcuts that are overriding Amethyst's. I've looked in SysPrefs/Keyboard Shortcuts, as well as some of the other apps like Alfred and Keyboard Maestro, but there's nothing with those matching key combinations.

Is there a way to globally retrieve ALL possible keyboard shortcuts that are currently active across the system?

Comment: idk the answer to this, but you need to make sure you specify the actual numpad key - macOS does differentiate for shortcuts between numbers on numpad & above qwerty.

Comment: Yeah I knew about this (learned the hard way) but it's a good tip for whoever's scratching their head with the numpad confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found something that partially answers my need: [Paletro](https://appmakes.io/paletro) so I figured I'd drop this here for whoever else might need it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322802)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [ShortcutDetective](https://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) could help. From the website:

> ShortcutDetective detects which app receives a keyboard shortcut
> (hotkey). This is useful because sometimes you aren't able to register
> a shortcut in an app like SizeUp and want to know why.

You need to scroll down the page to find the app.

Tools like [KeyCue](https://ergonis.com/keycue) and [KeyClu](https://sergii.tatarenkov.name/keyclu/support/) show a list of available keyboard shortcuts, although usually for system wide and the frontmost application's keyboard shortcuts.